# Admin-Ajax.php, SSL, Non-SSL

Tags: htaccess, wp-config, ssl, https

I have a WordPress site behind a reverse proxy. The site is over http, except the wp-admin area, which is under https. We don't have BasicAuth or anything running on top of the admin area.

One of our front-end plugins is failing because it's making a call to https://admin-ajax.php from a front-end http page, and browsers don't seem to like that behavior. (If it matters, the URL string contains nonces)

What's the best way to allow for front-end calls to admin-ajax.php? Should I redirect all calls to that file from https to http? If yes, how can I do that while still requiring all other files under /wp-admin to be under https?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

PS: The code below is what we currently have in wp-config:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: sounds like you need to fix the plugin, or it might be that the plugin is right and you should serve the whole page under https

Comment: Front end Ajax is tricky especially with sites trying to hide ssl URLs. Trust me I know. The best way to approach this is with WordPress's new REST API.

Comment: close voting as obviously the problem is with the plugin for which the code is not given

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API? This would place all your requests under `/wp-json` instead, bypassing the issue entirely, just keep in mind you will want to serve authenticated `wp-json` requests over SSL. Consider changing your rules to users who have cookies, rather than wp-admin requests

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to define this constant in your `wp-config.php` to force HTTPS on admin:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Also, there is a function called `is_admin()` which could be helpful in your case.

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

However, if you have a rule in your web server forcing all `wp-admin` and `wp-login.php` requests to run over SSL, you will need to add an exception for `admin-ajax.php` file. Not sure how to implement this in Apache, but for NGINX the easiest way would be something like:

```
if ($request_uri !~* "^/wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php") { rewrite "^/wp-(admin|login)" https://$host$request_uri permanent; }
```

Hope this helps!